# Calculate peak equity in autofiltered sheet

Tags: excel

I have a sheet which calculates the Peak Equity (CS) as well as the Total Equity (CR); both of these eventually wind up being different at some point, as one is calculating from the peak, whilst the other is just the current total.

The difficulty always comes with anything like this when autofiltering, so I need some assistance

I have a formula (two actually) which works well on Total Equity (CR), even when the sheet is autofiltered.

Both `=10000+SUBTOTAL(109,CR$18:CR18)` and `=AGGREGATE(9,7,CR$18:CR18)+10000` do the job perfectly. I have used the SUBTOTAL one in this sheet

To calculate the Peak Equity (CS), requires finding the maximum of either the previous Peak Equity (CS) or current Total Equity (CR). The first row (CS18) is not able to use the same formula as there is no previous data row, so in this cell (CS18), I used the starting bank in the calculation instead.

Assuming the first row of data is 18, the basic formula in column CS is `=MAX(CR19,CS18)`. This formula works fine when the sheet is not filtered, but falls over when it is autofiltered, for obvious reasons. Is there a way to have column CS be dynamic, always showing the correct Peak Equity?

As an afterthought, could the starting bank be possibly part of the formula to help resolve the issue? I'm just not sure how to address this issue. It doesn't matter what that bank is, but let's just use 10000 as a starting point for now if that helps.

Some additional explanation is needed so hopefully I can make what clearer

The first 17 rows are taken up with performance statistics. After that:

Profit or Loss is column N,
Current Bank is column CR,
Bank Highest Position (Peak) is CS

CR is the current total of what is visible in N - `=10000+SUBTOTAL(109,N$18:N18)`

CS needs to always be the larger of CR of the current row and CS of the previous row, but how is that possible in the first visible row as there is no previous row to use?

As the first 17 rows are taken up with data showing strike rates etc, whatever row is in position 18 will basically need to fulfil this `=N18+10000` with 10000 being the starting bank

A couple of provisos change things a little, though, as CS can never be below the starting bank figure, let's assume 10000, so if the first row of N was a loss, CS would still be 10000, if that makes sense. As profit grows, CS also grows, but it can never go backwards, as it is always the peak. CR is simply the current $ amount in the bank. CS is the high point and will always be greater or equal to CR..

So I'll try it in English. CS would be something like this

IF current row is the first row, then the higher of N + 10000, or 10000. IF not the first row, then the higher of 10000, CR of current row or CS of row above.

I hope this helps a little bit, as I am not sure how to express this in a formula which will work when filtered

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: I can still see issues with whatever will be the first row of data after autofiltering. The first row after filtering won't be able to reference any row of data above it, as none exists, so how to compensate for that fact?

Comment: I think you can also use AGGREGATE() function here for max like `=AGGREGATE(4,4,CR19,CS18)`

Comment: Just in case my explanation initially was not clear; row 18 is the first data row, so in CS18, it is not possible to have ```=AGGREGATE(4,4,CR18,CS17)``` as CS17 has no data in it. That is only ever an issue for whichever is the first row after filtering, but since that is not known, how to allow for it? That was why I thought of possibly adding in the starting bank somehow. Thanks again

Comment: In short after filtering you want to get max between `CR18` and first data cell of CS column. I t may be CS17, Cs20 or CS25 blah blah..... right?

Comment: It can never be CS17 as 18 is the first row of data. That was my point. The first 17 rows are taken up by boxes showing statistics, so the 18th is row 1 for data. After filtering, you want higher of CR in the new first row and the profit (N) + starting bank (though CS can never be below the starting bank). I will add some further information in the original post

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the starting bank value, how about wrapping the peak equity function inside IFERROR, like so:
IFERROR( *function* , starting bank value or cell reference)

Comment: cheers and thanks for your reply, Amgad. I have added some more explanation in the original post above which hopefully clarifies some of what is required in column CS

Comment: I think the IFERROR idea could be a good one. The peak equity function inside would need to be the higher of CR of the current row, or CS of the row above, but again, how to calculate on filtered rows? If there is no row above, that obviously means this is the first row of data, so would not that first row always give the IFERROR reply of the bank start value? ```=IFERROR(MAX(CR18,CS17), 10000)``` I'm still lost as to how to have this apply to filtered rows, as with this formula here, there is no CS17 and MAX doesn't works with filtered data and SUBTOTAL(104 will want a range, not just 2 cells